# I'm getting a new pc without an OS, so can I download Ubuntu onto a CD on a separate laptop, then put that CD into the disk drive on the new PC?

Tags: 14.04

I'm getting a new pc without an OS, and I'm wondering if I could download Ubuntu onto a CD, on a separate laptop, then put that CD into the disk drive on the new PC? Can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: You need DVD as Ubuntu is too large for CD. But many new systems do not have DVD/CD. And it is faster/easier in most cases to use USB flash drive. And USB3 flash in USB3 port which all new systems have is fast compared to old USB2.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. (Though Ubuntu is too big for a CD. You'll need a DVD) I'd recommend waiting three days so you can get 16.04LTS though...

Comment: agree. just stick the CD/DVD into your reader and make sure that when you turn the computer on to select to boot from your CD/DVD drive first. also i too would suggest downloading the 16.04LTS.

Answer (score 0):

You can burn it to a CD or to a USB Stick and boot. If you don't want to spare a CD, then USB is better. If the other laptop is running on Ubuntu, you're so lucky to use "Startup Disk Creator" built in.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The good thing is that you can go to the Ubuntu website and then download the iso file and then put it on to usb. One good thing, is that by not having any other os on the system, you will not have any dual booting. You lucky person, it can be a bit of a pain.The usb option would be the way to go though and waiting for the latest build.